sql statement in dbt macro returns 4 fileds in 1 row, how to capture it in model
In dbt with snowflake db, I have a macro that returns 4 fields in single row, by running sql. How to capture its result in my dbt model. I am getting below errors.
macro:
{% macro mac_em_edw_delta_attributes(em_schema_in,em_table_in,edw_schema_in,edw_table_in,exclude_columns_in) %}
--start maco
{% set var_sql_stmt %}
...<some complex sql cte statements>...
SELECT
    listagg('em_table.'||COLUMN_NAME,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) AS COLUMNS_LIST_EM,
    listagg('edw_table.'||COLUMN_NAME,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) AS COLUMNS_LIST_EDW,
    listagg('em_table.'||COLUMN_NAME||' As '||COLUMN_NAME||'_em, '||'edw_table.'||COLUMN_NAME||' As '||COLUMN_NAME||'_edw',',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) AS COLUMNS_SELECT,
    listagg('em_table.'||COLUMN_NAME||'<> edw_table.'||COLUMN_NAME,' OR ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) AS COLUMNS_EXPR
FROM columns_to_compare 
{% endset %}

{% set var_sql_resut = run_query(var_sql_stmt) %}

{% if execute %}
      {{ return(var_sql_resut) }}
  {% else %}
      {{ exceptions.raise_compiler_error("Error executing SQL query: " ~ var_sql_stmt) }}
{% endif %}
    
--end maco
{% endmacro %}

model:

{{
    config(
    materialized='view'
    )
}}

--dynamic variables/ Edit only first 5 variables
{% set var_em_schema = 'ENTERPRISE_MODEL_HRC' %}
{% set var_em_table = 'MATERIALDIM' %}
{% set var_edw_schema = 'ENTERPRISE_MODEL_HRC' %}
{% set var_edw_table = '_EDW_UAT_TRDW_MATERIALDIM' %}
{% set var_natural_keys = 'MATERIAL' %}
{% set var_exclude_columns = 'MATERIAL_KEY' %}
--static variables
{% set var_always_exclude_columns = 'UPDATE_TIMESTAMP' %}
{% set var_sql_resuts_out = mac_em_edw_delta_attributes(var_em_schema,var_em_table,var_edw_schema,var_edw_table,var_exclude_columns) %}
{% set var_columns_list_em_out = var_sql_resuts_out.columns[0].values()[0] %}
{% set var_columns_list_edw_out = var_sql_resuts_out.columns[0].values()[1] %}
{% set var_columns_select_out = var_sql_resuts_out.columns[0].values()[2] %}
{% set var_columns_expr_out = var_sql_resuts_out.columns[0].values()[3] %}

--Final Select
--Goes for VIEW
SELECT
    {{var_columns_select_out}}
FROM {{var_em_schema}}.{{var_em_table}} em_table
JOIN {{var_edw_schema}}.{{var_edw_table}} edw_table
ON em_table.MATERIAL = edw_table.MATERIAL
WHERE {{mac_hkey_generator(var_columns_list_em_out)}} <> {{mac_hkey_generator(var_columns_list_edw_out)}}

Error:Error executing SQL query: <entire sql in macro>
When I try to just place sql in macro and run it from model using run_query(macrocall).. getting below Error:
Compilation Error in model _materialdim_em_edw_vw (models\final\_materialdim_em_edw_vw.sql)
  'None' has no attribute 'table'. This can happen when calling a macro that does not exist.


I think you have several problems here.

I believe you should move if execute outside of the macro.

{% macro mac_em_edw_delta_attributes(em_schema_in,em_table_in,edw_schema_in,edw_table_in,exclude_columns_in) %}
...
{% set var_sql_resut = run_query(var_sql_stmt) %}
{{ return(var_sql_resut) }}    
--end maco
{% endmacro %}

{% set var_sql_resuts_out = mac_em_edw_delta_attributes(var_em_schema,var_em_table,var_edw_schema,var_edw_table,var_exclude_columns) %}
{% if execute %}
{% set var_columns_list_em_out = var_sql_resuts_out.columns[0].values()[0] %}
{% set var_columns_list_edw_out = var_sql_resuts_out.columns[1].values()[0] %}
{% set var_columns_select_out = var_sql_resuts_out.columns[2].values()[0] %}
{% set var_columns_expr_out = var_sql_resuts_out.columns[3].values()[0] %}
{% else %}
{% set var_columns_list_em_out = '' %}
{% set var_columns_list_edw_out = '' %}
{% set var_columns_select_out = '' %}
{% set var_columns_expr_out = '' %}
{% endif %}


You select different rows of the first column, not different columns of the first row.

{% set var_columns_list_em_out = var_sql_resuts_out.columns[0].values()[0] %}
{% set var_columns_list_edw_out = var_sql_resuts_out.columns[1].values()[0] %}
{% set var_columns_select_out = var_sql_resuts_out.columns[2].values()[0] %}
{% set var_columns_expr_out = var_sql_resuts_out.columns[3].values()[0] %}

